# Оплаты(сбербанк, тинькофф). Телеграм бот на python

Tags: python, платежи

Можете посоветовать какие-то библиотеки на python, возможно на др. языках или другие варианты решения для создания чеков оплаты и их проверки(как qiwip2p)

Answer (score 1):

Все намного проще. Не надо усложнять себе задачу - у Киви Банка или Яндекс Кассы есть api для python. С первым Вы знакомы, так и используйте его, qiwi предоставляет возможность оплачивать без комиссии с большинства банковских карт.